# Backtracking algorithm for permutations

Tags: permutations

I am looking at the backtracking algorithm for computing permutations, and although I can understand what is happening, I cannot understand how it solves the problem for any value of `h` elements.

How are proofs that algorithm is correct made.  Can one show that by swapping, one gets all possible arrangements ?  Is there any mathematical book about recursion ?

Can anyone explain to me a proof that leads to the backtracking algorithm ?

Here is the algorithm in `C++` using a string to play scrabble.

To run an example of all permutations call `permute ("abc" 0 3)`

```
void permute(string& a, int i, int h)
 {
  if (i == h)
    cout << a << endl;
  else {
    for (int j = i; j < h; j++) {
      swap(a[i], a[j]);     // Swapping done
      permute(a, i + 1, l); // Recursion called
      swap(a[i], a[j]);     // backtrack
  }}}
```

When `i=h` this will generate

```
abc acb bac bca cab cba
```

Now, let's do `permute ("abcd" 0 4)`.  Now things really become complicated.  Although I have done the example, understood the backtracking procedure, and that one gets all possible permutation of letters, I find difficulty starting on a proof of correctness.

Comment: This question is too general for an answer here. The usual way to prove a recursive algorithm correct is by structural induction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction. Try seaching for _structural induction permutations and combinations_

Comment: What algorithm are you talking about?

Comment: Had a look at structural induction but without much idea about what I have to do for this case.  Would need help about how to approach this algorithm and that it produces all permutations.  Any ideas would be much welcomed.

Comment: What kind of things need I learn to check such algorithms.  I do not think that it is a very difficult algorithm but have not come up with anything to start with.

Comment: Your code isn't right. The loop condition should be $\mathtt{j < l}$. When you have fixed that, try to to come up with a description of what the $i$ parameter means: executing some test runs on simple examples may help. Once you understand that, you will be much closer to finding an inductive proof of correctness.

Comment: You are quite right.  I have done all that, and also completed the case of `permute ("abcd" 0 4)`.  I understand the backtracking procedure.  Am done with examples, but have problem starting about an inductive proof.  That it works for all cases of general length `h`.

Comment: `i` indicates the depth level.  When the deepest level is reached, we spit out a one of the `4!` possibilities.

Comment: That's not a good description of how it works. Try stepping through a call like $\mathtt{permute("abcd", 2, 4")}$.

Comment: The elements preceeding i are left untouched. I also get to "abcd" again.  Which gets all permutations from index `i` onwards.

Comment: Doing the Base Case is easy.  Prove that the algorithm works correctly for the smallest possible input, a string with only one letter.  But I am struggling with the Inductive Step. Showing that if the algorithm works correctly for words of length `h`, it also works correctly for words of length `h+1`. This involves showing that the algorithm generates all permutations for a word of length `h+1` and does not produce duplicates or miss any valid permutations.